# populate value to select2 while update in yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2

I am trying to update my value which I have stored in table using select2 in yii2.

```
var ele=$('div#containerStockUnit');
ele.find('button').attr('data-id',edit.attr('data-id'));
ele.find('input[name="Listitems[Title]"]').val(edit.parents('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
ele.find('input[name="Listitems[ParentID]"] ').val(edit.parents('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text());
ele.find('input[name="Listitems[Value]"]').val(edit.parents('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text());
```

I used above code to get value to select2 input named  `ParentID`.

How can I populate value to the column using jquery???

Comment: post you controller code, your view code, wich type of column do you want to populate? alle this fields are in a form?